# Running precompiled java files from the command line (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, classpath, shared-libraries

I checked (based on [cannot execute binary file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184280/bash-filename-cannot-execute-binary-file) and some other SO questions) that the java file I'm trying to run is indeed executable on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
$ file ORA/include/OraFiles/bin/ora
ORA/include/OraFiles/bin/ora: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

But when I try to run it

```
$ ORA/ora.sh -measures ORA/include/OraFiles/xml/ora_xml_measures.xml -script junkin.xml -log 1999-progress.log
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/cmu/casos/OraUI/controller/OraMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.cmu.casos.OraUI.controller.OraMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: edu.cmu.casos.OraUI.controller.OraMain. Program will exit.
```

or

```
$ ORA/include/OraFiles/bin/ora -measures ORA/include/OraFiles/xml/ora_xml_measures.xml -script junkin.xml -log 1999-progress.log
ORA/include/OraFiles/bin/ora: error while loading shared libraries: liborautils.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

however `liborautils.so.0` does in fact exist:

```
$ ls ORA/include/OraFiles/bin/
construct.exe              libjogl_cg.so               libora.so.0
dynetml2orgahead.exe       libjogl.jnilib              libora.so.0.0.0
gluegen-rt.dll             libjogl.so                  liborautils.so
html_to_ppt_converter.exe  libnetstatplusfog.so        **liborautils.so.0**
j3dcore-ogl.dll            libnetstatplusfog.so.0      liborautils.so.0.0.0
jogl_awt.dll               libnetstatplusfog.so.0.0.0  libtinyxml.so
jogl_cg.dll                libnetstatplus.so           libtinyxml.so.0
jogl.dll                   libnetstatplus.so.0         libtinyxml.so.0.0.0
libcasos_utils.so          libnetstatplus.so.0.0.0     ora
libcasos_utils.so.0        libnewran.so                ora.exe
libcasos_utils.so.0.0.0    libnewran.so.0              ora_jni.dll
libgluegen-rt.jnilib       libnewran.so.0.0.0          ora_log.txt
libgluegen-rt.so           libora_jni.so               orgahead.exe
libjogl_awt.jnilib         libora_jni.so.0             orgahead_perf.exe
libjogl_awt.so             libora_jni.so.0.0.0
libjogl_cg.jnilib          libora.so
```

How do I make Java see that it's there? I'm trying to run `ng-nailgun` but the instructions on [nailgun quickstart](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/quickstart.html) don't seem to relate to the Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install nailgun`.

I installed `ant`, `nailgun`, and `maven2` in the hopes that their dependencies would install whatever java stuff I need. This is on a 64-bit EC2 prebuild of Ubuntu 12.04.1.

---

**UPDATE:** Here is the text of `ora.sh`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./include/OraFiles/bin/lib:./include/OraFiles/bin
java -splash:include/OraFiles/images/ORA-splash-screen.png -Xmx1024m -cp ora.jar:lib/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar:lib/jfreechart-1.0.13-swt.jar:lib/TableLayout.jar:lib/jcommon-1.0.9.jar:lib/httpcore-nio-4.0-beta3.jar:lib/j3dcore.jar:lib/httpcore-4.0-beta3.jar:lib/jung.jar:lib/twitter4j-1.1.7.jar:lib/jcalendar.jar:lib/rssutils.jar:lib/omj3d.jar:lib/json-1.0.jar:lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar:lib/jsi-generics.jar:lib/opencsv-1.7.jar:lib/trove-2.0.4.jar:lib/xml-writer.jar:lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar:lib/junit.jar:lib/jts-1.7-generics.jar:lib/casosparser.jar:lib/jgraphlayout.jar:lib/htmlparser.jar:lib/facebook-util-1.8-final.jar:lib/j3d-vrml97.jar:lib/omcorba.jar:lib/ant-launcher.jar:lib/colt.jar:lib/wwj/worldwind-ora.jar:lib/freehep/freehep-graphics2d-2.0.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-widgets-swing-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-svggen-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/spatialdb-0.1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/velocity-1.4.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-go-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/jsr108-0.01.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/db2jcc_dummy-8.2.1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-postgis-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-xml-gml3-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-xml-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/concurrent-1.3.4.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-image-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/jaxb-impl-1.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-tiger-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/imageioext-asciigrid-1.0-rc1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-api-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-shapefile-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-main-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-validation-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/commons-jxpath-1.2.jar:lib/freehep/freehep-graphicsio-svg-2.0.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/ecore-2.1.0.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/postgis-driver-1.0.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/commons-beanutils-1.4.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/relaxngDatatype-X.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-db2-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/geowidgets-1.0-M1.jar:lib/jai_codec.jar:lib/freehep/freehep-graphicsio-2.0.jar:lib/jogl/jogl.jar:lib/freehep/freehep-io-2.0.1.jar:lib/freehep/freehep-xml-2.0.1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/ant-optional-1.5.1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-vpf-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-demo-property-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/commons-pool-1.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-cql-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/geoapi-nogenerics-2.1-M2.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-sde-dummy-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/vecmath-1.3.1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/velocity-dep-1.4.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-coverage-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-util-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-wms-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/jaxb-api-1.3.jar:lib/omsvg.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-xml-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-bridge-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/commons-lang-2.1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-render-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-dom-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-graph-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-epsg-hsql-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-indexed-shapefile-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/jlfgr-1.0.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-hsql-2.3.3.jar:lib/java-getopt-1.0.13.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-svg-dom-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/common-2.1.0.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-geotiff-2.3.3.jar:lib/toolkits_1-2-0.jar:lib/milStd2525_png.jar:lib/j3dutils.jar:lib/JAXWS2.1.3-20071218.jar:lib/Jama-1.0.1.jar:lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-imagemosaic-2.3.3.jar:lib/iText-2.1.0.jar:lib/commons-math-1.2.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/postgresql-8.1-407.jdbc3.jar:lib/freehep/freehep-util-2.0.1.jar:lib/idw-1.5.0/idw.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-awt-util-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-gtopo30-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-wfs-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/picocontainer-1.2.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-arcgrid-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-mysql-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-openoffice-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-ext-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-oracle-spatial-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-gvt-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-svgsupport-2.3.3.jar:lib/svgSalamander-tiny.jar:lib/jhall.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-css-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-mappane-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-demo-mappane-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-directory-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-geomedia-2.3.3.jar:lib/activation.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-mif-2.3.3.jar:lib/openmap-4.6.5.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-xml-filter-2.3.3.jar:lib/httpmime-4.0-beta2.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/junit-3.8.1.jar:lib/jai_core.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:lib/mail.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/hsqldb-1.8.0.1.jar:lib/jogl/gluegen-rt.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/commons-cli-2.0-gt2-pre1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/commons-io-1.2.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/xsd-2.1.1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-demo-data-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-transcoder-1.6.jar:lib/javaml-0.0.12.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-epsg-access-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/jta-1.0.1B.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-epsg-postgresql-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-referencing-2.3.3.jar:lib/freehep/freehep-graphicsio-pdf-2.0.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-brewer-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar:lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/imageioext-customstreams-1.0-rc1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar:lib/httpclient-4.0-beta2.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/jaxb-libs-1.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-imagepyramid-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-script-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/xsdlib-20050614.jar:lib/facebook-java-api-1.8-final.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-arcsde-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-coveragetools-2.3.3.jar:lib/MDateSelector14-00347.jar:lib/rome-1.0.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-shapefile-renderer-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-epsg-wkt-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-gml-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/log4j-1.2.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/xml-apis-xerces-2.7.1.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/batik-parser-1.6.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-xml-gml2-2.3.3.jar:lib/gt2-2.3.3/gt2-referencing3D-2.3.3.jar:lib/jdom-1.1.jar:lib/jide-oss-2.8.8.jar edu.cmu.casos.OraUI.controller.OraMain
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ant.

Comment: @carlspring My mistake. I've now removed the tag. Thanks.

Comment: Those voting to close: how is this not a programming question? Do I need to ask this on superuser?

Comment: Does `liborautils.so.0` point to `liborautils.so`? Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/ORA/include/OraFiles/bin:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and have that point to an absolute path.

Comment: @carlspring Using `ls -la` as described [here](http://superuser.com/questions/71163/how-to-find-all-soft-links-symbolic-links-in-current-directory) I don't see that any of the files are pointers. Here are the java binaries I am using: http://www.casos.cs.cmu.edu/projects/ora/download.php. Thanks for helping me.